# etaremune fails: "undefined control sequence"

Tags: xkeyval

I'm having a perhaps embarassingly simple problem with the package etaremune.  It seems to crash both latex and pdflatex with a command derived from xkeyval.  Here's the .tex file that crashes for me:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etaremune}

\begin{document}
hi
\end{document}
```

And here's the pdflatex output:

```
> This is pdfeTeX, Version 3.141592-1.21a-2.2 (Web2C 7.5.4) entering
> extended mode (./testeta.tex LaTeX2e <2003/12/01> Babel <v3.8d> and
> hyphenation patterns for american, french, german, ngerman, b ahasa,
> basque, bulgarian, catalan, croatian, czech, danish, dutch, esperanto,
> e stonian, finnish, greek, icelandic, irish, italian, latin, magyar,
> norsk, polis h, portuges, romanian, russian, serbian, slovak, slovene,
> spanish, swedish, tur kish, ukrainian, nohyphenation, loaded.
> (/usr/local/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls Document
> Class: article 2004/02/16 v1.4f Standard LaTeX document class
> (/usr/local/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
> (./etaremune.sty
> (/usr/local/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty
> (/usr/local/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex
> (/usr/local/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/keyval.tex))) !
> Undefined control sequence. l.39 \XKV@for@n
>                {topsep,partopsep,itemsep,parsep,leftmargin,rightmargin,% 
> ?
```

Any insights that you might have into what I'm missing would be appreciated; let me know if there's more information needed to assess the problem!

Comment: 'LaTeX2e <2003/12/01>' --- perhaps you need to update your `TeX` distribution.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX by the way.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You seem to have downloaded `etaremune.sty` in the work directory, but are using a quite old TeX distribution. This is not going to work, because the current version of `etaremune` uses features of `xkeyval` that were added in a later version than you have. But downloading the new `xkeyval` could produce other similar problems. Update your TeX distribution, instead.

Comment: Hmmm.  I seem to have the latest version according to my FreeBSD ports, but yeah, I see your point about the 2003 business.  Will try to get a newer version and will report back.

Comment: Install from upstream.

Comment: Is there any news from this?